# How can I populate my UITableview with Data that I retrieved from a PFquery?

Tags: uitableview, pfquery

I'm new to objective-C and I am having an issue populating my UItableview with data I retrieved from Parse.
Here is my query:
    - (void)viewDidLoad {

```
[super viewDidLoad];
PFQuery *query = [PFUser query];
[query orderByAscending:@"username"];
[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    } else {
        //this is my users array
        self.allUsers = objects;
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    }
}];
```

I have logged this and can see that I successfully retrieved the data. But when I try to populate my tableView as follows. No data shows up. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

return [self.allUsers count];

}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


PFUser *user = [self.allUsers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

cell.textLabel.text = user.username;

return cell;
}
```

Thanks in Advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement:

`- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView`.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah I have that set. I didn't include it. turns out my network connection timed out so I wasn't getting the data anymore. Thank you though.